# Java: Manipulation of Lists with super classes

Tags: java, inheritance, collections

Suppose I have `MyEdge` and `MyEdgeModified`, such that `MyEdge` is the superclass and `MyEdgeModified` is the subclass. Now, suppose I do this:

```
List<List<MyEdge>> collectionOfEdgeLists = new LinkedList<List<MyEdge>>();
for(int i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
    List<MyEdgeModified> newList = someMethod();
    collectionOfEdgeLists.add(newList); //ruh roh
}
```

Now, if I do this:

```
private List<MyEdge> convert(final List<MyEdgeModified> list) {
     final List<MyEdge> otherList = new ArrayList<MyEdge>(list.size());
     for(Edge edge : list) {
         otherList.add(edge);
     }
     return otherList;
}
```

Then:

```
collectionOfEdgeLists.add(convert(newList)); //ok...
```

Now, the problem I'm seeing here is that I can treat each individual `MyEdgeModified` as an `Edge`, but if I have a collection I have to first build a whole 'nother list to be able to use it. Why? Am I doing something wrong? This seems wrong and dumb to me.

Comment: `List<? extends List<? extends MyEdge>>` or just `List<List<? extends MyEdge>>`?

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem, because outside of the class, I need to treat each individual List as `List<MyEdge>`. I tried `List<List<MyEdge>> collectionOfEdgeLists = new LinkedList<List<? extends MyEdge>>();` but that didn't work.

Comment: `return new ArrayList<MyEdge>(list);` should do the job, thanks to wildcards.

Comment: @Tom yeah that made the code a lot cooler. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
List<MyEdgeModified> modifiedList = new List<MyEdgeModified>();

// This is what you want to do, but which doesn't work
List<MyEdge> edgeList = modifiedList;

// Now this would have to be valid...
edgeList.add(new MyEdge());

// And this should be valid too...
MyEdgeModified modified = modifiedList.get(0);
```

... but you've managed to put a reference to an instance of `MyEdge` into a `List<MyEdgeModified>` - so you've managed to break type safety.

That's what the rules are there to prevent.

Now what you *can* do is use wildcards:

```
List<MyEdgeModified> modifiedList = new List<MyEdgeModified>();
List<? extends MyEdge> edgeList = modifiedList;
```

At that point, you won't be able to *add* to `edgeList`, but you can take items from it... so all is safe.

Now creating a `List<List<? extends MyEdge>>` ends up being trickier again... I can't remember offhand whether it's even allowed...

In general, the best place to look for details of this sort of thing is [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the absence of covariance in Java generics.

Covariance means that for some type `T` and subtype `S`, `List<S>` is a subtype of `List<T>`.

This is not the case in Java.  For the reasoning, assume that covariance exists and consider the following case:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> oList = stringList; // Just referring to a subtype as its supertype
oList.add(new Object()); // nothing wrong with adding an Object to a List<Object>
for (String s : stringList) { ... }  // now what?
```